# delete html tag, but not the tag content

Tags: html

I have a bunch of Word docs which were "saved as" filtered html.  The html files contain extraneous ole-links which I need to delete.  For example, I want to replace:

```
<h3><a name="OLE_LINK25">My Section Title</a></h3>
```

with

```
<h3>My Section Title</h3>
```

Any suggestions for how I might do this, in an automated way?

Comment: Care to tell us what language you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) could help to remove all anchor tags with name starting with "OLE".

```
Elements anchors = doc.select("a[name^=OLE]");
for (Iterator it = anchors.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    Element anchor = it.next();
    String text = anchor.text();
    Element header = anchor.parent();
    header.text(text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this (untested, make sure to test first):

```
sed -i".backup" 's/<([^ ]+) name="OLE[^"]*">([^<]+)<\/\1>/\2/g' *.html
```

What this will do is replace all occurrances of `<TAG name="OLE....">WHATEVER_HERE</TAG>` with just `WHATEVER_HERE` in all *.html files.  It will also make a backup of each *.html file from *FILENAME.html* to *FILENAME.html.backup*

If necessary, download
[sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)

Or [gnu sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/sed.html)

Comment: Thanks very much!  I ended up going with the jsoup approach, but your suggestion looks good too.  Much appreciated.